# Using a static_assert in a macro

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a situation like this:

```
#define FOO(Readonly) static_assert(Readonly, "Fire!");
```

`Readonly` will obviously literally pasted as "false" or "true" so the `static_assert` will always fire. How do I write a conditional in place of `Readonly` so that the `static_assert` works properly?

---

Here is my intended usage:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y
#define GET_SET(Name, Readonly) decltype(Name) CAT(get, Name)() const { return Name; } \
void CAT(set, Name)(decltype(Name) value = decltype(Name)()) { \
    static_assert( /* Insert Magic bullet here */ , #Name " is read-only."); \
    Name = value; \
}

class Test
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    GET_SET(x, false)
    GET_SET(y, true)
};
```

Example preprocessor output:

```
decltype(x) getx() const { return x; } void setx(decltype(x) value = decltype(x)()) { static_assert(!false, "x" " is read-only."); x = value; }
decltype(y) gety() const { return y; } void sety(decltype(y) value = decltype(y)()) { static_assert(!true, "y" " is read-only."); y = value; }
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5da9e86a669a40bd)

Comment: What's `Readonly` coming from? Why will it make the assert always fire?

Comment: What doesn't work about this?

Comment: @aaronman This is probably an X and Y problem, but it always seem to fire for my stated reason.

Comment: I tested it it seemed to work fine

Comment: @aaronman I posted a Coliru link. My intention is to only have the static_assert fire if you attempt to call `sety`.

Comment: `true` and `false` evaluate to `true` and `false` respectively, so your assumption that will always fire is not true.

Comment: If you write `static_assert(false, "...");` it's *always* going to fail, regardless of whether you even instantiate the type or not, let alone calling a member function.

Comment: `static_assert` is static, it happens at compile time, not at run time.

Comment: You don't really want static_assert, you want to disable the set procedure. Why generate it in the first place? Have two separate GET and GET_SET macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro directive

```
#define FOO(Readonly) static_assert(Readonly, "Fire!");
```

will, as you correctly surmise, forward the value passed into Readonly, so

```
FOO(false)
```

will generate

```
static_assert(false, "Fire!");
```

Bearing in mind that `static_assert` asserts when the condition is false, this will always fire. However

```
FOO(true);
// generates
static_assert(true, "Fire!");
```

which will never assert.

In your desired output you wrote:

```
decltype(x) getx() const { return x; } void setx(decltype(x) value = decltype(x)()) { static_assert(!false, "x" " is read-only."); x = value; }
```

It appears you just forgot the `!` infront of ReadOnly in your macro.

`static_assert` is a compile time keyword, it's checked at compile time, not run time, so unless there's some reason it can't be resolved until the template is instantiated (e.g. it's checking against a template-typed member variable or a template parameter) then it's always going to fail at the declaration.

The following code appears to work fine:

```
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)

#define CAT_(x, y) x ## y

#define GET_SET(Name, Readonly) decltype(Name) CAT(get, Name)() const { return Name; } \
  void CAT(set, Name)(decltype(Name) value = decltype(Name)()) { \
    static_assert( !Readonly , #Name " is read-only."); \
    Name = value; \
  }

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Foo() : x(0), y(0) {}
    GET_SET(x, false);
    GET_SET(y, true);
};
```

http://ideone.com/BkRYBE

Except that, of course, it barfs on the bad case because we've used `static_assert` instead of a run-time assert or throw. But it does what you've stated you wanted it to do.